# Using matrices to normalize transformed images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, matrix, transformation

Consider the two images below (original and transformed respectively). The three blue squares (markers) are used for orientation.

[image: Original] [image: Transformed]

Original Image:

- We know the width, height
- We know the (x,y) coordinates of all three markers.

Transformed Image:

- We can detect the (x,y) coordinates of all three markers.
- As a result, we can calculate the angle of rotation, the amount of (x,y) translation and the (x,y) scaling factor.

I now want to use the System.Drawing.Graphics object to perform RotateTransform, TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform. The trouble is, the resulting image is NEVER like the original.

I've been told on stack overflow that the order of applying transformations does not matter but my observation is different. Below is some code that generates an original image and attempts to draw it on a new canvas after introducing some transformations. You can change the order of the transformations to see different results.

```
public static void GenerateImages ()
{
    int width = 200;
    int height = 200;
    string filename = "";
    System.Drawing.Bitmap original = null; // Original image.
    System.Drawing.Bitmap transformed = null; // Transformed image.
    System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = null; // Drawing context.

    // Generate original image.
    original = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
    graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(original);
    graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.MintCream);
    graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, 0, 0, original.Width - 1, original.Height - 1);
    graphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 10, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, original.Width - 31, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, original.Width - 31, original.Height - 31, 20, 20);
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Original.png");
    original.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    graphics.Dispose();

    // Generate transformed images.
    transformed = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
    graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(transformed);
    graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
    graphics.ScaleTransform(0.5F, 0.7F); // Add arbitrary transformation.
    graphics.RotateTransform(8); // Add arbitrary transformation.
    graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 50); // Add arbitrary transformation.
    graphics.DrawImage(original, 0, 0);
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Transformed.png");
    transformed.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    graphics.Dispose();
    transformed.Dispose();

    original.Dispose();

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
}
```

I can see two potential issues here:

- Since the transformations are being applies one after another, they render the originally calculated values useless.
- The graphics object applies rotation at the (0, 0) coordinate where as I should be doing something different. Not sure what.

Comment: Your second possibility is likely. Though you were told the order of transformations does not matter, this is not true in the general case. Scaling and Translation are both commutative, and mutually commutative. Rotation is only commutative under some restrictions - in particular you have to be rotating about some point of the image not the coordinate system within which the image resides. Sorry can't help with the code however.

Comment: @ChrisWalton: Thanks. I gather that I need some kind of a linear function to calculate one vector relative to another rather than applying transformations this way. I'm looking at the [Linear Transform Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) to see if it is what I need.

Comment: Just tried out your code, it produces different results even without rotating, by just changing the order of scale and translate.

Comment: @Xantix: Exactly! I'm not familiar with transformations so not sure whether my approach is wrong or the code implementation is wrong.

Comment: I need help in calculating angle of rotation and scaling. I know points from original and new image. Please guide me. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59467047/4723876

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx), the Graphics.Drawing transformations are performed by multiplying matrices together in the order in which you apply the transformations.

With integers, a*b*c = b*a*c

However, with matricies, ABC almost never equals BAC.

So, it appears the order of transformations does matter, since matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Put another way, it seems that if I do the following on your picture:

case 1:

- translate (100,50)
- scale (0.5,0.7)

picture ends up with top-left corner at: (100,50)
and bottom-right corner at: (200,190)

case 2:

- scale (0.5,0.7)
- translate (100,50)

picture ends up with top-left corner at: (50,35)
and bottom-right corner at: (150,174)

This means that by scaling first, and then translating, that the scaling will also scale the amount of translation, that is why in case two the the picture ended up at (50,35) for the top left corner, half of the translated X and .7 of the translated Y.